# how to set data in widget's text view,data coming from web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

Anyone give me advice about how can I set data in the widget's text view, that data come from web service and web service return string response like name from table. I am new in android development so please help me

Comment: please elaborate your question which webservice you are using share your code

Comment: I am using WCF web service that is parsing by soap

Comment: public string Recods()
        {
            var query = (from c in db.Tests where c.id == 4 select c.Username).SingleOrDefault();
            return query.ToString();
        } this is my method in .svc file

Answer (score 0):

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

this will initialize view

String string ="you soap result";

text.setText(string);

set text

Comment: but in widget where can I parse the data from web service? in which method of widget provider class I call web service